# Query on parent child related objects in Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, community, dynamic-soql

There are 2 objects Account & Address and their relationship is master detail.

In address there is a checkbox called primary and most of the accounts will have 1 address which is marked as primary.

I want to know the accounts which don't have a primary address at all. For example there are 2 accounts A & B. Account A has 5 addresses and none of them have primary checked and Account B has 5 address in which 1 is primary and the other 4 non primary.

So when I run a report saying primary=false i am getting both accounts A (5 records for each non primary address) & B (4 records for each non primary address) instead of only account A. This is because B has 4 addresses which are not primary and report is pulling them.

Is there any different way or query where I can get only account with no primary address which means by our example only account A should come out but not account B?

Comment: Can put picture of your report condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to create a roll up summary field on Account, filtering by the Primary field. You can then run reports where Primary Addresses equals 0.

For small databases, the following SOQL would also work:

```
Select Id From Account Where Id Not In
    (Select Account__c From Address__c Where Primary__c = True)
```

This would return all accounts that have no primary address. However, this query will fail for databases with hundreds of thousands of addresses.